# Android Navigation Deep Link - Ignore Query

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm attempting to add a deep-link for a URL that has the following format:

```
<deepLink
        android:id="@+id/deep_link"
        android:autoVerify="true"
        app:uri="my.example.com/articles/{slug}" />
```

This causes the `slug` argument passed to my destination to also include the query if it exists. For example, the URL `my.example.com/articles/recent-article?utm=1` results in the `slug` argument being `recent-article?utm=1`.

I've tried using the following pattern format in an attempt to ignore the query, but URLs no longer match correctly.

```
<deepLink
    android:id="@+id/deep_link"
    android:autoVerify="true"
    app:uri="my.example.com/articles/{slug}?*.*" />
```

Is there a way to effectively ignore the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the latest Navigation 2.2.0-rc04 (or one of the other Navigation 2.2 releases that adds support for query parameters), it sounds like you're hitting [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147447512) where deeplinks without query parameters don't ignore query parameters.

The workaround mentioned in the bug is to include a dummy parameter:

```
<deepLink
    android:id="@+id/deep_link"
    android:autoVerify="true"
    app:uri="my.example.com/articles/{slug}?dummy={dummy} />
```