# Android deeplink path, pathPrefix or pathPattern not working

Tags: android, ionic-framework, deep-linking, capacitor

I am trying to make Android deeplinking work only for specific urls e.g.:

- https://books.com/book/nice-title-of-a-book
- https://books.com/book/abc-for-dummies

So http://books.com/about keeps linking to the webpage

This configurations in my `AndroidManifest.xml` works and opens the correct page in my app. The issue is that this matches every page on books.com

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="@string/custom_url_scheme" />

    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="books.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

When I change the data part into:

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="books.com" android:path="/book/nice-book-1" />
```

or

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="books.com" android:pathPrefix="/book" />
```

or

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="books.com" android:pathPattern="/book/..*" />
```

to match only `/book` followed by a slug, it does not work a all.

I've already found many similar questions on Stackoverflow but they are either quite dated or not handle the situation where an url works with slugs.

- [Android Navigation Deep Link - Ignore Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59776914/android-navigation-deep-link-ignore-query)
- [Intent filter using path,pathPrefix, or pathPattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395938/intent-filter-using-path-pathprefix-or-pathpattern)
- [How to use PathPattern in order to create DeepLink Apps Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436111/how-to-use-pathpattern-in-order-to-create-deeplink-apps-android)

Does anyone have run into the same issues when matching only a few urls with slugs?

Comment: I have the same problem,  android:pathPrefix="/ar/"  doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me a very long time to figure this out. So I'll answer my own question to save others precious time.

It turned out that when running an Android app on a device via Android studio

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="books.com" />
```

Is the only path that will work.

When using:

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="books.com" android:path="/book/nice-book-1" />
```

or

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="books.com" android:pathPrefix="/book" />
```

These will only work when using a ***SIGNED*** version of the app on your device. This probably because in your `assetlinks.json` there is a `sha256_cert_fingerprints` which can only be verified when a signed app is used.